# Automated Load test with 100 new users order product at the same time using jmeter each time to use the unique user

Tags: jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I have an online order site. How to Load test with 100 new users order a product at the same time using JMeter(not one user after another. Order with 100 users at the same time).

For order submitting user has to go multiple pages like as Menu > Checkout > Basket > Your Details with email & password > Payment > Confirmation page. I have tried it by BlazeMeter recorder tools for 1 user order process and then save as a JMX file and then import it on Jmeter. Finally unable to get a solution. I have passed 2-3 days did not get a solution. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all make sure that the test works fine for 1 user as record-and-replay in the majority of cases won't produce a valid script due to dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) (at least add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan to automatically handle [Cookie-related headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)). So inspect each request and response details using View Results Tree listener and amend your test so each request will give the anticipated result up to the payment confirmation page.
2. Once you will be able to run test successfully several times with 1 user you will need to get the list of 100 username/password combinations and save it into a CSV file. Then add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the credentials from the file and replace recorded hard-coded username and password with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the CSV file

Comment: Thank you for the response, Can I perform the same test using the chrome driver(Chromedriver in jmeter) i am able to do it for 1 user